# Automatic formatting for user entered date in Adobe Form

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe

I'm new here, but I can't seem to find an answer to this question and my JS knowledge is amateur at best.

I have a PDF form that I have built so my team can create and then laser etch a nameplate. One of the fields is a manufacture date for the product. I tried setting the date format to ddmmmyyyy, but I also need the date in uppercase, which the Adobe date format doesn't seem to do.

I've done a metric ton of research and the best I could find is this:

```html
event.value = util.printd("ddmmmyyyy", new Date()).toUpperCase();
```

This works great, except it enters today's date and I don't know how to modify it in order to make it work with a user entered date.